# Exibir bairro de acordo com a Cidade - CAKEPHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Estou utilizando `cakephp` em um projeto de imobiliárias, quando eu for adicionar uma imobiliária o cliente seleciona a cidade, então, preciso que seja listado a lista de bairros desta cidade....

View/add:

```
    echo $this->Form->input('cidade', array('label' => 'Cidade', 'empty' => 'Selecione uma Cidade', 'options' => $Cidades));
    echo $this->Form->input('bairro', array('label' => 'Bairro', 'empty' => 'Selecione o Bairro', 'options' => array()));
```

Ajax chamando o pagesController(onde eu pego os bairros da cidade):

```
    $('#ImovelCidade').change(function(e) {
    $('#ImovelBairro').html($('<option />').val('').text('Carregando...'));
    $.getJSON(
        "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'pegarBairros')) ?>", 
        { "cidade" : $(this).val() }, 
        function (data) { 
            $('#ImovelBairro').html($('<option />').val('').text('Selecione'));
            $.each(data, function (chave, valor) {
                $('#ImovelBairro').append($('<option />').val(chave).text(valor));
            } );
        }
    );
```

PagesController:

```
     public function pegarBairros ($cidade = null) {
    $this->layout = 'json';
    $result = array();

    if (in_array($_REQUEST['cidade'], array_keys($this->cidade))) {
        $this->loadModel('Bairro');
        $bairros = $this->Bairro->find('list','fields' => array('id','bairro'), 'conditions' => array('cidade' => $this->cidade[$_REQUEST['cidade']]));
        foreach ($bairros as $id => $bairro) {
            if (!empty($bairro)){
                $result[$id] = $bairro;
                $arr = $result;
                json_encode($arr);
            }
     }
    } else $result[] = 'error';
    $this->set('data', $arr);
}
```

addController:

```
        public function add () {
            if ( !empty($this->request->data) ){ 
                    $data = $this->request->data;
                    if ($data['Imovel']['opcoes']) $data['Imovel']['opcoes'] = implode(';', $data['Imovel']['opcoes']);
                    $data['Imovel']['ativo'] = $data['Imovel']['ativoPeloAdm'] = 1;
                    $data['Imovel']['creator'] = $data['Imovel']['modifier'] = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.Imobiliaria.id');
                    if ($data['Imovel']['bairro']) {
                        $this->loadModel('Bairro');
                        $bairro = $this->Bairro->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $data['Imovel']['bairro']), 'order' => array('bairro ASC')));
                        $data['Imovel']['bairroNome'] = $bairro['Bairro']['bairro'];
                    }

                    if ($data['Imovel']['cidade']) {
                        $cidade = $this->Cidade->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $data['Imovel']['cidade'])));
                        $data['Imovel']['cidadeNome'] = $cidade['Cidade']['nome'];
                    }

                $data['Imovel']['especificacao'] = $data['Imovel']['imovel'];
                if ($this->Imovel->save($data)) $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
```

Comment: E qual exatamente é o problema?

Comment: eu seleciono a cidade, ai o na caixa do bairro, nao lista os bairros, apenas "Carregando..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara, eu tenho uma solução mais simples. Vai ter que mudar um pouco seu codigo.

Ao longo do codigo coloquei alguns comentarios pra te ajudar.

Vamos lá:

Sua view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('cidade', array('label' => 'Cidade', 'empty' => 'Selecione uma Cidade', 'options' => $Cidades));
echo $this->Form->input('bairro', array('label' => 'Bairro', 'empty' => 'Selecione o Bairro'); // retirei o array
```

Agora o javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#ImovelBairro').hide()

        $("#ImovelCidade").change(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: { select: $('#ImovelCidade').val()},
                url: '/pages/pegarBairros', // CRIAREMOS ESSE ACTION MAIS ABAIXO; ESSE ENDEREÇO IRÁ VARIAR, AJUSTE CONFORME SUA ACTION

                success: function(data) {
                          //preenche o select de bairros com os dados que retornam do ajax.
                     $("#ImovelBairro").html(data).show();

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Agora, criamos a action `pegarBairros` onde ela receberá a `id` da cidade e pegará o bairro correspondente

```
function pegarBairros() {

    if($this->request->is('ajax')) {

        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->set('bairros',$this->Bairro->find('list','fields' => array('id','bairro'), 'conditions' => array('cidade' => $this->request->data['select']]));)))
 // $this->request->data['select'] é a cidade que vem do Ajax
        );
    }
}
```

Por último, criamos a `view` da action `pegarBairros` para que contenha as options:

```
<option value="">Selecione</option>
<?php foreach($bairros as $bairro): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $bairro['Bairro']['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $filial['Bairro']['bairro']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Caso tenha alguma dúvida ou não dê certo por algum motivo, só comentar...

Comment: e essa view...eh so criar ela na pasta do Imovels? @IgorMartins

Comment: eu mudei meu codigo, nao consegui fazer do seu jeito, eu alterei e tenho o seguinte, ele mostra os bairros, porem, ele nao esta pegando o valor.. vc tem skype?

Comment: As views são referentes as suas actions... meu skype: igor.martins88

Answer (score 0):

@Furlan,

Você está fazendo em Php puro ?...caso seja em Wordpress eu tenho uma ideia boa para você um simples tutorial fácil e explicativo, é um form de pesquisa muito bom comigo deu certo vou deixar o link da uma olhadinha.

http://arresteddeveloper.net/wordpress-create-a-meetings-listings-and-filter-using-a-custom-post-type-and-ajax/