# Populando select através da opção de outro select

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-2

Tenho um sistema feito em CakePHP.

Tenho 3 selects em uma view:
Um pra listar os estoques;
Um pra listar os locais do estoque (Um estoque pode ter vários locais);
E um pra listar os produtos que tem no local determinado;

Como faço pra, ao selecionar um estoque, aparecer os locais daquele estoque e assim sucessivamente ?

Tenho todas as variáveis já na view, sendo necessário apenas filtrar.

Comment: Coloque como está o seu código agora - pelo menos um exemplo parecido (dois ou tres campos por tabela, e as queries que você) - senaoq uem for responder vai ter que recriar tudo o que você tem aí.

Já adianto que se você está usando um sistema de html estático (sem requisições assíncronas (ajax) vai precisar reformular bastante coisa.

Comment: Duplicada desse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10758/como-mudar-conteudo-de-um-select-a-partir-de-outro-select)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como mudar conteudo de um select a partir de outro select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10758/como-mudar-conteudo-de-um-select-a-partir-de-outro-select)

Comment: Encontrei ajuda nesse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7557/exibir-bairro-de-acordo-com-a-cidade-cakephp